# Does ie4linux work under Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, wine

I'm trying to install ie4linux, following [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-internet-explorer-6-7-on-fedora-10-11)

#### root

```
yum install wine cabextract
```

#### normal user

```
wget -q http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/downloads/ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
tar xfz ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
cd ies4linux-*
sed -i 's/which wineprefixcreate/which iptables/g' lib/functions.sh
./ies4linux --no-flash --no-desktop-icon --no-menu-icon --no-gui --beta-install-ie7 # Same as above but with IE7 support (beta)
```

But when installing, the installer suddenly terminates:

```
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/ADVAUTH.CAB: No such file or directory
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/CRLUPD.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/HHUPD.CAB: WARNING; possible 6720 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/IEDOM.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/IE_EXTRA.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/IE_S1.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/IE_S2.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/IE_S3.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/IE_S4.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/IE_S5.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/IE_S6.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/SETUPW95.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file.
/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/VGX.CAB: WARNING; possible 6896 extra bytes at end of file.
```

How can I install this on Fedora 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install Internet Explorer on Fedora OS, it's not possible in this way this because this is not use anymore and not working properly much. I was trying everything to install this and I understand it's not working anymore. If you want to install IE on Fedora, you should try [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks).

Comment: It still says: "/home/user/.ies4linux/downloads/ie6/HU/SETUPW95.CAB: WARNING; possible 6968 extra bytes at end of file." - after installing winetricks - so the solution is that it doesn't works. :\

Comment: no no you just after winetricks installation just type winetricks press "enter" after you will see windows and you can select whatever you need it 

Thanks ..